No ObservableObject of type found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for "ClassName" may be missing
ToggleView is unable to access the manager class environment object
I have fully identified the cause of the crash to be because of my attempt in trying to access an environment object when presenting the swiftUI view from a view controller presented as a sheet presentation controller.
I have attached the full test source code to cause the crash. I have also attached .environmentObject as well which is not shown here.
How do I fix this case? Do I have to pass my class multiple levels down when I have like multiple classes that needs to be passed down in my actual app?
class ManagerClass: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = ManagerClass()
    
    @Published var isEnabled = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        UIList()
    }
}

struct UIList: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let tableViewController = UITableViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITableViewController {
        tableViewController.tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableViewController.tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableViewController.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return tableViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UITableViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        let parent: UIList
        
        init(_ parent: UIList) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Tap me"
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            presentSheet()
        }
        
        func presentSheet() {
            let sheetVC = SheetViewController()
            if let sheet = sheetVC.sheetPresentationController {
                sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
                sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
                sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
                sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
                
                parent.tableViewController.present(sheetVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SheetViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
            CellView()
        }
        return cell
    }
}

struct CellView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ToggleView()
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var managerClass: ManagerClass

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Enable", isOn: $managerClass.isEnabled)
    }
}


In your ContentView (or your App) you need to declare @StateObject private var  manager = ManagerClass(),
then pass this one source of truth to your other views using .environmentObject(manager). In the child views,
have @EnvironmentObject var manager: ManagerClass. Note you should not have your ManagerClass as a singleton, remove the shared.
When using .sheet you need to explicitly pass the model, eg ToggleView().environmentObject(manager).
See this link Monitoring data.

So I have to pass the manager class through my UIViewRepresentable views?

You will have to test this yourself. AFAIK, if you place @StateObject private var  manager = ManagerClass() high
in the views hierarchy, eg ContentView or App, it will be available to all child views, except the .sheet where you need to explicitly pass the model.
So try it keeping ToggleView().environmentObject(manager) see if it works without passing @EnvironmentObject var manager: ManagerClass to your UIViewRepresentable. If not put it in.

I can see 3 mistakes in that UIViewControllerRepresentable implementation. make needs to init the controller. You are missing update. Coordinator(self) self is a value not an object thus cant be used as a reference.

SwiftUI environment objects cannot automatically go through a UIKit "gap". If you had written the whole thing in SwiftUI, the toggle view will have successfully read the environment object.
You need to manually pass the manager through all the UIKit parts.
Here is the code. I have highlighted the parts where the manager is passed with comments.
class ManagerClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isEnabled = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // I put this here for a minimal reproducible example
    // you can put it further up the hierarchy if you like,
    // assuming there is no UIKit "gap"
    @StateObject private var manager = ManagerClass()
    var body: some View {
        UIList()
            .environmentObject(manager)
    }
}

struct UIList: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    // UIList needs to read this so that it can pass it further down
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: ManagerClass
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITableViewController {
        return context.coordinator.tableViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UITableViewController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.manager = manager
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(manager)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
        var manager: ManagerClass
        
        // You should not pass UIList to the coordinator
        // I redesigned this so that the coordinator holds the table VC itself
        init(_ manager: ManagerClass) {
            self.manager = manager
            super.init()
            tableViewController.tableView.delegate = self
            tableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self
            tableViewController.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        
        let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Tap me"
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            presentSheet()
        }
        
        func presentSheet() {
            let sheetVC = SheetViewController()
            // the manager is passed to the sheet VC here
            sheetVC.manager = manager
            if let sheet = sheetVC.sheetPresentationController {
                sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
                sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
                sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
                sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
                
                tableViewController.present(sheetVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SheetViewController: UITableViewController {
    var manager: ManagerClass?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        if let manager {
            // finally, the manager goes back into SwiftUI territory,
            // and SwiftUI handles the rest for us
            // CellView and ToggleView don't need to be changed
            cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
                CellView().environmentObject(manager)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}

If you have value types that you want to pass through a UIKit "gap", you can consider using a UITraitDefinition to automatically pass it through the UIKit territory. This is kind of like the UIKit version of EnvironmentKey.
